# How to use OAuth2 in Google AppEngine to call an API in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I have a web application hosted in Google app engine and i need to handle some APIs (calendar). I need to authenticate the user via OAuth and to call an API.

Comment: @maba: the API you refer to allows GAE to act as OAuth _service provider_, while OP needs GAE to be _service consumer_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess you are talking about the Google Calendar API, since you didn't specify. Information about using the Google Calendar API (in Java) is [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp). The document isn't specifically tailored to App Engine, but you can see some [App Engine examples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg/calendar-appengine-sample) in the client library distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`scribe-java`](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). It works on GAE. Or maybe [`scribe-up`](https://github.com/leleuj/scribe-up) which is an extension to it and supports getting user profiles out of the box.